# rails - Getting an id from the url and then passing it as an argument for creating an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First off I would like to ask how to redirect after clicking the submit button in a creation form. I have a form for creating a quiz and after they hit submit I want to redirect them to the link 'quiz/:id/add_question' where :id is the id of the just created quiz, but instead I just get redirected to /quizzes and it leads to a "The connection was reset" error in my browser.

Here is my quiz form:

```
<div>
<h2>Create Quiz</h2>
<%= form_for(@quiz) do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %> </br>

        <%= f.label :subject %>
        <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

And my quizzes controller:

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController
    def new 
        @quiz = Quiz.new
    end

    def create
        @quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)
        flash[:success] = "Quiz Created successfully" if @quiz.save
        redirect_to 'quiz/' + @quiz.id.to_s + '/add_question'
    end 

    private

    def quiz_params
        params.require(:quiz).permit(:name, :subject)
    end
end
```

The quiz/:id/add_question link leads to a question creation form:

```
<div>
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :question %></br>
    <%= f.text_field :question %></br>

    <%= f.label :answer1 %></br>
    <%= f.text_field :answer1 %></br>

    <%= f.label :answer2 %></br>
    <%= f.text_field :answer2 %></br>

    <%= f.label :answer3 %></br>
    <%= f.text_field :answer3 %></br>

    <%= f.label :answer4 %></br>
    <%= f.text_field :answer4 %></br>

    <%= f.label :correct_id %></br>
    <%= f.text_field :correct_id %></br>

    <%= f.submit "Add question" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The other part of my question is how can I pass another argument for the creation of the question object here. I don't want the user to enter that argument because the argument should be the id from the current url (quiz/:id/add_question).

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think you made a spelling error:

```
redirect_to 'quiz/' + @quiz.id.to_s + '/add_quesiton'
```

Should be

```
redirect_to 'quiz/' + @quiz.id.to_s + '/add_question'
```

But rather you should use the url helper that is available.

```
redirect_to quiz_add_question_path(@quiz.id)
```

Assuming thats the name of the route. You can find that name by running `rake routes`

For the id of the current quiz you can set a hidden attribute for example

```
<%= f.hidden_field :quiz_id, value: params[:id] %>
```

Comment: I fixed the spelling error and it still redirects me to just '/quizzes' when I looked at my routes I didn't have a prefix for my /quiz/:id/add_question

The hidden field works, thanks for that!

Comment: Can you share your routes.rb file?